# How to copy objects from the "default" DB to another DB with the same structure in Django

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, object

I have to migrate some data from one MySQL database to another one, both credentials are in the Django app settings file, accessible and everything is OK.

My setting file is like this:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'NAME': 'app_data',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'USER': 'mysql_user',
    'PASSWORD': 's3krit'
},
'prod_old': {
    'NAME': 'old_app_data',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'USER': 'mysql_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
}
}
```

What i am think so for: `document = Document.objects.using('prod_old').get(id=i)` then create another object in the default database using just `Document()` without specifying the DB (Django will use the default). If i call `Document().save()` do the ID coming from the `using('prod_old')` get copied to the "Default DB" ?

Can't find anything clear on this situation !
Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to initiate the class Document `justCreatedDocument = Document()`, and then call `save()` that will give it an auto-incremented ID in the database, then you have to save that ID, copy the object with `justCreatedDocument = oldDocument` and replace the ID with the one you copied, or the Document will be saved with an arbitrary ID.

This is the only solution I found !

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --database=default > old-fixture
python manage.py loaddata --database=pro_old old-fixture
```

Comment: just be sure that both database have the same tables

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, this is not what i need, I just have to move some entries on the Documents table, not all of it, and before migrating it, i'll have to add some additional data.